# Get GridViewColumn Header value from ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview, gridviewcolumn

I have this XAML code

```
<ListView Name="_lvContacts" ItemsSource="{Binding AccountPhonesList}"
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Path=ColumnHeader1}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Home}" Width="70" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Path=ColumnHeader2}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Office}" Width="70" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Path=ColumnHeader3}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Mobile}" Width="70" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Path=ColumnHeader4}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Other}" Width="70" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Path=ColumnHeader5}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Email}" Width="70" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

And this is code behind

```
            for (int i = 0; i < _lvContacts.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                string header = _lvContacts.Items[i].ToString();
                MyFunction(header);
            }
```

How can I get the GridViewColumn Header from ListView?I was trying to get GridView from ItemSources but this is already used by collection!I dont know what else I can say about this.

I hope this is understandable.

Comment: This is a bad approach. Don't try to get data from view or controls. Your GridViewColumn.Header is bound to ColumnHeader1/2/3... Try to get the data from there. If necessary you can use DataContext of ListView control.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your case you can do:

```
((GridView)_lvContacts.View).Columns[i].Header
```

Comment: GridView gridView = (GridView)_lvContacts.View;
string header = gridView.Columns[i].Header.ToString();
This was the solution of my problem,thanks a lot for idea!

Answer (score 10):

To get all of the headers, you can use the following code:

```
List<GridViewColumnHeader> headers = GetVisualChildren<GridViewColumnHeader>(_lvContacts).ToList();

public static IEnumerable<T> GetVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (child is T)
                yield return (T)child;

            foreach (var descendant in GetVisualChildren<T>(child))
                yield return descendant;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `GridView`, and the columns in the following way:

```
GridView gridView = (GridView)_lvContacts.View;
foreach(GridViewColumn column in gridView.Columns)
    // do something with column.Header. Your example:
    if (ItsTheColumnHeaderIWant(column.Header))
    {
        MyFunction(column.Header);
    }
```

Or, you can name the GridView in your xaml:

```
<GridView x:Name="_gridView"...>
```

And then you can just directly access it from code: `_gridView.Columns`.

Comment: Implied, but where `ItsTheColumnHeaderIWant()` tests the `column.Header` and returns a Boolean true value if it is the correct header value.  Great function name :)  -- though if we knew its name already, I'm not sure we'd need to test it :-P.  Still, got my vote.

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ!!!

```
  var headers = ((GridView) _lvContacts.View).Columns.ToDictionary(column => column.Header.ToString());
```